# What's the Difference between the Rspec and Rspec-Rails Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following in my GEMFILE:

```
group :development do 
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'annotate-models'
end 

group :test do 
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

What's the difference between 'rspec' and 'rspec-rails'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As stated on their wiki page:

> rspec-rails extends RSpec and Ruby on
>   Rails so you can specify the behaviour
>   of your rails web-app.

https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/rails

Whereas the rspec gem has no support for rails, providing a testing framework for plain old ruby applications.

Comment: Should be noted that the project has been moved to https://github.com/rspec/rspec/. [The new wiki](https://github.com/rspec/rspec/wiki/rspec-rails) doesn't include such a description for `rspec-rails` unfortunately, and neither does [the README](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#readme).